# How to make a permanent spot of light in a characters eyes?

Tags: lighting

At the moment, my character's eyes look lifeless and for the way, I made them, a spot of light in the eye usually fixes it. I'm wondering if there is a way to permanently make a spot of light in the eye so it looks better and something more like this:

[image]

(This isn't mine obviously) If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear it, thanks.

Comment: Hello :). In reality, you would put some *bright tiny light* in your scene. Eyes have an extremely wide 'field of view', so they pick up any bright area rather easily. You might want to experiment with the light's placement (near camera, up/down,...) for best results.

Comment: Alright, I'll have to try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the right materials and light setup so you can replicate this look I recommend the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPK6JlWESM8

For Anime-Style Chractere it looks better to take a .png/.jpg file, split it into white/transparent and attach it to the armature of the iris. VRoid has some complete models ready for download free of charge.

Comment: This sounds awesome. Thanks sooooo much I'll have to try this.